# using two async call in flutter only one resolved

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I'm trying to get weather data with two futures but only one is resolved.
I have two async methods getCurrentWeather and getForecasts and getCurrentWeather is not resolve but if I remove getForecasts then getCurrentWeather future is resloved.

What do I miss?

```
class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
  // Future<List<Weather>> weatherField;
  Future<Weather> weatherFuture;

  Future<List<Weather>> getForecasts() async {
    List<Weather> forecasts = await weatherStation.fiveDayForecast();
    return forecasts;
  }

  Future<Weather> getCurrentWeather() async {
    Weather current = await weatherStation.currentWeather();
    return current;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder<Weather>(
                    future: getCurrentWeather(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Text(snapshot.data.country);
                      }

                      return Text('Loading');
                    })),
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<Weather>>(
                    future: getForecasts(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        List<Weather> weathers = snapshot.data ?? [];
                        return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: weathers.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              Weather weather = weathers[index];
                              return ListTile(
                                leading: Text('aaaa'),
                                title: new Text(weather.weatherDescription),
                                onTap: () {},
                              );
                            });
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                      }
                      // By default, show a loading spinner.
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                    // color: const Color(0xFFFFE306)
                    ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Everything looks correct in your code. Maybe the issue has to do with `weatherStation`'s implementation or configuration?

Comment: Try removing one of the expanded wrappers.

Comment: still not working after removing Expanded